# Simulating a click on a div added dynamically not existing in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

As I understand an ajax callback adds a new `div` to the html on my end. I can see this element added in the html however I can't access it through DOM for some reason. I tried calling it from the console in chrome and a js bookmarklet **after** the element was already visible/added to the html. I am not sure why the DOM is not picking it up but that's another question I guess...

This is the div:

```
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div>
```

And I used the below to grab a reference to it but 90% of the time it returns a null (occasionally, it actually returns a reference but I honestly don't know /understand why):

```
document.querySelector(".recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark");
```

I have been looking at [different ways to bind to this new div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) so I can execute a click on it after it appears in the html/dom but I am having trouble putting this together as it seems you can bind to a `click` event but you can't bind to something like a `shown` event :/

So this is what I currently have but it doesn't work as (I guess) it's based on a `click` event and I am not actually clicking it?

```
var host = document.querySelector("head");
if(host){

    var importJquery = function(){
        var jquery = document.createElement('script');
        jquery.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js")
        host.appendChild(jquery);
    }

    importJquery();

    var bindToCaptcha = function(){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.innerHTML = '$(document).on("click", ".recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark", function(e) {alert("clicked: %o",  this);});';
        host.appendChild(script);
    }

    bindToCaptcha();
}
```

So just to be clear I want to identify the moment this div shows up in the html and execute a click on it but can't since I am missing a reference to it.

I was considering running a loop at an interval checking whether the div existed but I would rather like to stay away from that approach (and also I am not sure this would work because the DOM doesn't always seem to return a reference this div).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that appends the `.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark` div?

Comment: what are you trying to do (high level) because this seems like a weird way of doing it, whatever it may be

Comment: @sklingler93 I would but I am not sure how to find it :/ I looked at what happens onclick that triggers this div to show up but there's just a massive js file that doesn't have any reference to `recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark` or perhaps I am looking at a wrong place. I am new to this so please forgive me.

Comment: @Damon at gamdom.com, there is a chat that shows a link every few minutes that you have to click to grab some free stuff and I am trying to automate it. After clicking the link a captcha box pops up and most of the time you just have to click in the box and youre done. So I got to detect when the link shows up but then I can't grab a reference to the captcha box to automate the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the reference because the element I was after was located within an iframe. I feel like this question would have been answered instantly by someone else had I mentioned the iframe in the first place but I am new to this so I wasn't even aware of it until I have done some further digging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MutationObserver` API to detect when a child is added to a parent element:

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Example taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the mean time I've found a solution to my problem; I couldn't get the reference because the element I was looking for was located within an iframe. I feel like this would have been answered instantly have I mentioned it in the first place but I am new to this so I wasn't aware.